# Installing a package with `straight` fails with the error `"use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :straight"`

Tags: use-package, straight.el

I have this

```
  (defvar bootstrap-version)
  (setq straight-repository-branch "develop") ; Need this for new org-contrib location
  (let ((bootstrap-file
     (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
    (bootstrap-version 5))
    (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
      (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
       'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))
    (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
  (straight-use-package 'use-package)

;By default, use-package uses package.el to install packages. To use straight.el instead of package.el:
  (use-package evil-commentary
    :straight t)


; Make sure this is nil, so we do not use package.el
  (setq use-package-always-ensure nil
  ; FIXME: use a debug var for all of config?
    use-package-verbose 'debug  
    )
```

..and get this

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :straight")
  error("use-package: %s" "Unrecognized keyword: :straight")
  use-package-normalize-plist(evil-commentary (:straight t) nil use-package-merge-keys)
  use-package-normalize-keywords(evil-commentary (:straight t))
  #f(compiled-function (name &rest args) "Declare an Emacs package by specifying a group of configuration options.\n\nFor the full documentation, see Info node `(use-package) top'.\nUsage:\n\n  (use-package package-name\n     [:keyword [option]]...)\n\n:init            Code to run before PACKAGE-NAME has been loaded.\n:config          Code to run after PACKAGE-NAME has been loaded.  Note that\n                 if loading is deferred for any reason, this code does not\n                 execute until the lazy load has occurred.\n:preface         Code to be run before everything except `:disabled'; this\n                 can be used to define functions for use in `:if', or that\n                 should be seen by the byte-compiler.\n\n:mode            Form to be added to `auto-mode-alist'.\n:magic           Form to be added to `magic-mode-alist'.\n:magic-fallback  Form to be added to `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n:interpreter     Form to be added to `interpreter-mode-alist'.\n\n:commands        Define autoloads for commands that will be defined by the\n                 package.  This is useful if the package is being lazily\n                 loaded, and you wish to conditionally call functions in your\n                 `:init' block that are defined in the package.\n:autoload        Similar to :commands, but it for no-interactive one.\n:hook            Specify hook(s) to attach this package to.\n\n:bind            Bind keys, and define autoloads for the bound commands.\n:bind*           Bind keys, and define autoloads for the bound commands,\n                 *overriding all minor mode bindings*.\n:bind-keymap     Bind a key prefix to an auto-loaded keymap defined in the\n                 package.  This is like `:bind', but for keymaps.\n:bind-keymap*    Like `:bind-keymap', but overrides all minor mode bindings\n\n:defer           Defer loading of a package -- this is implied when using\n                 `:commands', `:bind', `:bind*', `:mode', `:magic', `:hook',\n                 `:magic-fallback', or `:interpreter'.  This can be an integer,\n                 to force loading after N seconds of idle time, if the package\n                 has not already been loaded.\n:demand          Prevent the automatic deferred loading introduced by constructs\n                 such as `:bind' (see `:defer' for the complete list).\n\n:after           Delay the effect of the use-package declaration\n                 until after the named libraries have loaded.\n                 Before they have been loaded, no other keyword\n                 has any effect at all, and once they have been\n                 loaded it is as if `:after' was not specified.\n\n:if EXPR         Initialize and load only if EXPR evaluates to a non-nil value.\n:disabled        The package is ignored completely if this keyword is present.\n:defines         Declare certain variables to silence the byte-compiler.\n:functions       Declare certain functions to silence the byte-compiler.\n:load-path       Add to the `load-path' before attempting to load the package.\n:diminish        Support for diminish.el (if installed).\n:delight         Support for delight.el (if installed).\n:custom          Call `Custom-set' or `set-default' with each variable\n                 definition without modifying the Emacs `custom-file'.\n                 (compare with `custom-set-variables').\n:custom-face     Call `custom-set-faces' with each face definition.\n:ensure          Loads the package using package.el if necessary.\n:pin             Pin the package to an archive." #<bytecode -0x1d24114e05fd6909>)(evil-commentary :straight t)
  macroexpand((use-package evil-commentary :straight t) nil)
  macroexp-macroexpand((use-package evil-commentary :straight t) nil)
  macroexp--expand-all((use-package evil-commentary :straight t))
  macroexp--all-forms((if d/on-droid nil (defvar bootstrap-version) (setq straight-repository-branch "develop") (let ((bootstrap-file (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory)) (bootstrap-version 5)) (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file) (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straigh..." 'silent 'inhibit-cookies) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp))) (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage)) (straight-use-package 'use-package) (use-package evil-commentary :straight t) (setq use-package-always-ensure nil use-package-verbose 'debug)) 1)
  macroexp--expand-all((if d/on-droid nil (defvar bootstrap-version) (setq straight-repository-branch "develop") (let ((bootstrap-file (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory)) (bootstrap-version 5)) (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file) (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straigh..." 'silent 'inhibit-cookies) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp))) (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage)) (straight-use-package 'use-package) (use-package evil-commentary :straight t) (setq use-package-always-ensure nil use-package-verbose 'debug)))
  macroexpand--all-toplevel((if d/on-droid nil (defvar bootstrap-version) (setq straight-repository-branch "develop") (let ((bootstrap-file (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory)) (bootstrap-version 5)) (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file) (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straigh..." 'silent 'inhibit-cookies) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp))) (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage)) (straight-use-package 'use-package) (use-package evil-commentary :straight t) (setq use-package-always-ensure nil use-package-verbose 'debug)))
  internal-macroexpand-for-load((if d/on-droid nil (defvar bootstrap-version) (setq straight-repository-branch "develop") (let ((bootstrap-file (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory)) (bootstrap-version 5)) (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file) (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straigh..." 'silent 'inhibit-cookies) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp))) (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage)) (straight-use-package 'use-package) (use-package evil-commentary :straight t) (setq use-package-always-ensure nil use-package-verbose 'debug)) t)
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x546ac11e495cb80>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b8a75>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Do you want to evaluate this on android only? Perhaps you mean `when` instead of `unless`?

Comment: No, when not on Android, cause Android does not support Straight.

Comment: And on what kind of system do you get the backtrace? Maybe that system does not support `straight` eiher?

Comment: Needless to say, all of these details *should be part of the question*.